# problems with integer declaration and Array count instruction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am programming an application in which I have a list of users received from server in format JSON. Later I extract from that JSON the data of each user and I have created an object called UsersController with four fields (I don't know if this is the adequate word) called prod_id, userName, userThumb and createTime. In my ViewController I have an object of UsersController and an array for store all the users.
The code of the class UsersController is:

```
//UsersController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UsersController : NSObject{
    NSInteger *prof_id;
    NSString *createTime;
    NSString *fullName;
    NSString *thumb;
}

@property (nonatomic) NSInteger *prof_id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *createTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *fullName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *thumb;


@end

//UsersController.m
#import "UsersController.h"

@implementation UsersController

@synthesize prof_id;
@synthesize fullName;
@synthesize createTime;
@synthesize thumb;

@end
```

And in ViewController.m I have the following code:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


 NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSArray *array_webdata=[[NSArray array] init];

NSString *searchStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    

array_webdata = [parsedata objectWithString:searchStatus error:nil];

//String with all data of each user
NSString *usersList = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"results"];    
NSLog(@"\n usersList =\n %@ \n", usersList);

//extract data from the JSON data received from the server
NSArray *userName = [usersList valueForKey:@"fullname"];    
NSArray *userID = [usersList valueForKey:@"prof_id"];
NSArray *userThumb = [usersList valueForKey:@"thumb"];
NSArray *userCreateTime = [usersList valueForKey:@"createTime"];    

NSMutableArray *arrayUsuarios = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: [userID count]];
int i;
UsersController *usuarioSimple;
UsersController *usuarioAuxiliar;
for (int i=0; i<[userName count]; i++) {
    usuarioSimple = [[UsersController alloc] init];
    usuarioAuxiliar= [[UsersController alloc] init];

    //I store in the object called usuario the extracted data from JSON userName, userID, userThumb y userCreateTime
    usuarioSimple.prof_id = [userID objectAtIndex:i];
    usuarioSimple.fullName = [userName objectAtIndex:i];
    usuarioSimple.thumb = [userThumb objectAtIndex:i];
    usuarioSimple.createTime = [userCreateTime objectAtIndex:i];

    [arrayUsuarios addObject:usuarioSimple];

    usuarioAuxiliar = [arrayUsuarios objectAtIndex:i];

    NSLog(@"pruebaConsulta.prof_id[%@]:    %@",i, usuarioAuxiliar.prof_id);
    NSLog(@"pruebaConsulta.fullName[%@]:   %@",i, usuarioAuxiliar.fullName);
    NSLog(@"pruebaConsulta.thumb[%@]:      %@",i, usuarioAuxiliar.thumb);
    NSLog(@"pruebaConsulta.createTime[%@]: %@\n",i, usuarioAuxiliar.createTime);
    [usuarioSimple release];
    [usuarioAuxiliar release];

}

[searchStatus release];
[connection release];
[webData release];
[pool drain];

}
```

And here I have two problems. The first is the declaration of ***i*** used in bucle for. I don't know why but when I execute, when it has to show the value of ***i***, displays (null).

The second problem is when I use [userID count], [userName count], [userThumb count] or [userCreateTime count]. This instructions doesn't work because if I write this line:

```
NSLog(@"userid count: %@", [userID count]);
```

the execution crashes and says EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
I proved a lot of possible solutions but always fails, please I need your help. Thanks.

ps: sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%i` or `%d` to include integers in a formatted string. See [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

Comment: I was looking for it but I didn't found anything, Thank you!!. Now displays the value of i and makes the full bucle but the problem with count instruction continues if I make a NSLog and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

count will return you an primitive integer.

%@ is used to print Strings or  any Object's String description.

as DrummerB has said use %i or %d for integers.

```
NSLog(@"userid count: %d", [userID count]);
```

You get EXC_BAD_ACCESS because NSLog thinks you have passed a pointer to an object which turns out to be a bad access for you.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is not an object, it is a type and you declare prof_id as an NSInteger*,this means a pointer to an integer, not an object.

You cannot pass messages to an NSInteger or it's pointer since it is not an object.  You also cannot add it to an array or dictionary.  You want to use NSNumber, which encapsulates a number (such as an integer).  You can then pass aroun the NSNumber as an object but retrieve the integer value by sending it the integerValue message.

```
NSInteger myInt = myNumber.integerValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1.When you do this: NSLog(@"userid count: %@", [userID count]);
 use %d instead of %@.

1. when you do this :
   [arrayUsuarios addObject:usuarioSimple]; //you add object at the last index .

   usuarioAuxiliar = [arrayUsuarios objectAtIndex:i]; //here you access object at index i, if i> [arrayUsuarios count], it will crash.

In this situation, you call this method: [arrayUsuarios lastObject];

Comment: Don't worry, I understand. Thanks!!